# Shading Artifacts while Using Normal Map?

Tags: texturing, shaders, lighting, normal-map, artifacts

I assigned a Quixel gross skin material to a model, and it seems the lighting gets messed up when I have the Normal map p[lugged in.  The material looks fine if I unplug the normal map. The model isnt very high res, but the topology seems fine.

Any idea why this is happening, and how to fix it?

[image: With Normal Plugged In]

[image: Without Normal Map]

[image: Node Setup]

[image: Topolgy seems fine]

Comment: what does it give if you switch the Image Texture node with the normal image from sRGB to Non-Color?

Comment: Probably need to turn down strength to .02 or so.

Comment: @moonboots, changing from sRGB to non color just lessens the contrast of the shadows, but they still result in the blocky artifacts

Comment: could you please share your object (keep only a part of it if you don't want to share the whole object)? Also pack the images

Comment: @AllenSimpson  I want to have the detail the normal map gives.  Turning it virtually off doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @moonboots , its not object specific, I just tried the texture on the Suzanne monkey, and get shading artifacts with the normal map there too

Comment: so could you please share the texture with Suzanne? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sure, just realize that strength of 1 means the shader is trying to imitate bumps as tall as 1 meter, .02 is just under an inch.  That distance is where the super dark shadows are coming from, so just dial it in to your preference.